# Cannot get the Id through the API in the component(Angular, .net core)

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I'm developing a test project for learning Angular. My problem - the student's id from the service is equal to null. I have a controller - StudentController to work with data. Here is a snippet of code where I get data on students:

```
// GET: api/students
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        var students = _unitOfWork.Students.GetAll();
        return Ok(students);
    }
```

And here is my domain model(Student.cs) with UnitOfWork method - GetAll():

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId{get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime bDate {get;set;} 
}
```

GetAll(Repository.cs):

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _entities.ToList();
    }
```

Next,I created a service for getting data from the API(student.service.ts):

```
  private readonly _StudentsUrl: string = "/api/students";
GetAll()
{
    return this.http.get(this._StudentsUrl)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

So, in the client part student's id is undefined.
(students.component.ts)

```
   export class StudentsComponent {
    students:Student[];
    constructor(private studentService: StudentService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.studentService.GetAll()
      .subscribe(students => this.students = students);
    }
}
    export class Student {
        StudentId: number;
        Name: string;
        bDate:DateTimeFormat
      }
```

In student.component.html i get students data, name and bDate properly, but StudentId is not.

```
<tr *ngFor="let st of students">
    <td>{{ st.StudentId }}</td>
    <td>{{ st.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ st.bDate }}</td>
    <td>
      <a [routerLink]="['/students/', st.StudentId]">View</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I tested my StudentController with Postman and everything is passed correctly.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Angular 5, .net core 2.0

Comment: Not be error in the .NET service?. Anyway are you using Http o HttpClient? You must use HttpClient and .map() operation in get() method not is neccessary. Check it.

Comment: console.log the raw json response and see if there's no typo on StudentId, if it exists at all or if it's null

Comment: It might be a problem that you wrote `<td>{{ st.name }}</td>` while it should be `<td>{{ st.Name }}</td>` the Name is with a capital letter in your class.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, but I found a solution by writing instead of StudentId on studentId. Now it works perfectly. So in html i change from:

```
<td>{{ st.StudentId }}</td>
```

to: 
`<td>{{ st.studentId }}</td>`

Modified code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let st of students">
        <td>{{ st.studentId }}</td>
        <td>{{ st.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ st.bDate }}</td>
        <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/students/', st.studentId]">View</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```